# Join with where in condition difficulties

Tags: mysql, sql, join, filter

I have `product` table and `product_attributes` table. I want filter products with necessary attributes, here is my sql:

```
SELECT * FROM product p 
INNER JOIN product_attributes p2 ON p.id = p2.product_id
WHERE p2.attribute_id IN (637, 638, 629))
```

But, it gives me all products even if product have only one attribute (637 for example). But i need products with all given attributes (637, 638, 629).

Comment: Showing some sample data and expected result would be helpful for us to help you.

Comment: You explicitly implement the WHERE clause to check for occurances in table p2. So you don't even try to limit to the final table. You need an outer SELECT for that and filter the derived table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fairly standard approach:

```
select * from product
where id in (
    SELECT id
    FROM product p 
    JOIN product_attributes p2 ON p.id = p2.product_id
      AND p2.attribute_id IN (637, 638, 629)
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(distinct attribute_id) = 3)
```

The HAVING clause ensures there were 3 different attribute ids (ie they were all found).

This can be expressed as a straight join (rather than the ID IN(...)), but it's simpler to read and should perform OK like thus.

Of slight interest may be the moving of the attribute id condition into the JOIN's ON condition.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian, please check out my comment at answer above

Comment: Is there any reason to use `AND p2.attribute_id` instead of `WHERE p2.attribute_id` ?

Comment: The optimized usually interprets them as the same, but done database do not. In general, putting it in the join condition will perform better (at least never worse).

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" subquery.  I like to solve these with aggregation and the `having` clause, because this is the most flexible solution:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p join
     product_attributes pa
     on p.id = pa.product_id
group by p.id
having sum(pa.attribute_id = 637) > 0 and
       sum(pa.attribute_id = 638) > 0 and
       sum(pa.attribute_id = 629) > 0
```

An alternative `having` clause is:

```
having count(distinct case when pa.attribute_id IN (637, 638, 629)
                           then pa.attribute_id
                      end) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product p 
INNER JOIN product_attributes p21 
        ON p.id = p21.product_id and p21.attribute_id = 637
INNER JOIN product_attributes p22 
        ON p.id = p22.product_id and p22.attribute_id = 638
INNER JOIN product_attributes p23 
        ON p.id = p23.product_id and p23.attribute_id = 629
```

Comment: I think this is bad approach, what if user want to filter on 50 attributes ? :)

Comment: In this case you should use query from another answers :)